# Form Validation with Dynamic Field Names

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic, jscript

I have a form but all fields need to be filled in before the form will submit.
I have experimented with adding HTML5 required = "required" which works fine on Chrome but not on IE.

Form field names are dynamic so I cannot reference them directly so needing some JavaScript code to loop through the inputs in the form then if the value is blank to focus the field with an alert and return false on the form submit.

I have started putting something together but my javascript is terrible ! Hoping yours is much better !

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validatelink2(){
for (var i = 0; i < document.forms['form1bxxx'].elements.length; i++) {
    var e = document.forms['form1bxxx'].elements[i];
    alert(e);
}
</script>



<form id="form1bxxx" name="form1bxxx" method="post" action="submitform.asp" onSubmit="return validateForm2(this)">

    <input name="veh<%=id%>" value="" type="text" id="veh<%=id%>" size="7" required="required" >

    <input name="date<%=id%>" type="text" id="date<%=id%>" size="10" onFocus="showCalendar('',this,this,'','holder1',0,30,1)">

    <input name="mile<%=id%>" type="text" id="mile<%=id%>" size="6">

    <input type="submit" name="button999" id="button999" value="Continue &gt;&gt;&gt;" onclick="return validatelink2(this);" />
```

Edit....

Updated Javascipt to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validatelink2(){
//Make sure required items are filled in
alert("hello");
  var x=document.getElementsByClassName('required');
  for(var i = 0; i <x.length; i++){
  alert("checking");
    if (x[i].value == null || x[i].value == "")
    {
      x[i].focus();
      alert("All Required Items are not completed.");
      return false;
    }
    }
    }
</script>
```

and I've set class required to have a background colour of yellow so I can see all the fields clearly with that class.

```
 <input name="veh<%=id%>" value="" type="text" id="veh<%=id%>" size="7" required="required" class="required" >
```

When I submit the form the hello alert comes up then form submits despite blank values.

Comment: so you need to check whether all inputs are filled?

Comment: yes exactly, updated question on recent progress.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class and use that to loop through the items and make sure they have a value.  This also allows for styling to show the field as required:

```
function submitRegClicked(){
//Make sure required items are filled in
  var x=document.getElementsByClassName('required');
  for(var i = 0; i <x.length; i++){
    if (x[i].value == null || x[i].value == "")
    {
      x[i].focus();
      alert("All Required Items are not completed.");
      return false;
```

}
   }

The message is ugly, but this should get you the idea.  Any item with a class of "required" will be checked.

Comment: I don't get the alert("All Required Items are not completed.") despite blank fields.

Comment: Works in Chrome. In IE I am get the error 
Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByClassName'

Comment: Is this an older version of IE?  When I do a search for [getelementsbyclassname internet explorer](https://www.google.com/search?q=getelementsbyclassname+internet+explorer&oq=getElementsByClassName+inter&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0j0i22i30k1l3.935.3221.0.6518.6.6.0.0.0.0.196.926.0j5.5.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.5.926.eWCpnin0Aik) I see many items which are older.

Comment: Internet explorer 11

Answer (score 0):

It's submitting because you aren't telling it to not submit.

You need to tell the submit event not to submit. You do this with `preventDefault()`.

Example:

```
function validatelink2(event){
  var x=document.getElementsByClassName('required');
  for(var i = 0; i <x.length; i++){
    alert("checking");
    if (x[i].value == null || x[i].value == ""){
      x[i].focus();
      alert("All Required Items are not completed.");
      event.preventDefault(); // form won't submit
      return false;
    }
  }

}

var the_form = document.getElementById("form1bxxx")
the_form.addEventListener("submit", validatelink2)
```

(In general, you should avoid using attributes like `onsubmit` in your HTML and instead put the logic into your JavaScript.)

See also: [How to Prevent Form From Being Submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted)

Comment: Made those changes, the form still submits and I don't get the alert ("All Required Items are not completed.") despite fields being blank.

Comment: Works in Chrome. In IE I am get the error Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByClassName'

Comment: Are you on an old version of IE? `document.getElementsByClassName` should be supported by IE9+. (The form is still going to submit if your script fails to get elements because your `for` loop will never execute and this `preventDefault()` never gets called.)

Comment: @Emma it would help if you made a jsfiddle for this to see your exact code.

Comment: Using internet explorer 11

Comment: <script async src="//jsfiddle.net/vyyc7xLd/2/embed/"></script>